# iOS 8 and segues throwing unexpected exception

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Well I'm coding an app with xcode 6.4 for iOS 8+, I have made a story board and connected several controllers the problem lies when I log out of the app and try to create a new user and go to the menu the app crashes I have an exception break point but I don't really understand why is crashing, any help?

The offending code:

```
@IBAction func listoTapped(sender: UIButton) {

if usernameRegisterField.text != "" && passwordRegisterField.text != "" {
    let user = PFUser()

    //2
    user.username = usernameRegisterField.text
    user.password = passwordRegisterField.text

    //3
    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { succeeded, error in
        if (succeeded) {
            //The registration was successful, go to the wall
            //self.performSegueWithIdentifier(self.tableViewWallSegue, sender: nil)
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier(self.showMenuSegue, sender: self)

            //self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        } else if let error = error {
            //Something bad has occurred
            self.showErrorView(error)
        }
    }

} else {

    var alert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Los campos no pueden estar vacios", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

}
```

And the segue crashing:

[image: Xcode screen segue]

It only crashes when I log out and then try to register a new user, I'm using a push segue.

EDIT: The solution to the no segues showing, is to enable size classes if you have them off, that will let you choose the show segue.

Comment: Seems like you'd know which line it was crashing at and what the exception is.

Comment: Yes is this self.performSegueWithIdentifier(self.showMenuSegue, sender: self), the exception no.

Comment: And are you sure your storyboard id for the segue is right?

Comment: Yes is "ShowMenu", now I'm logging out with       navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true), there is no error now it just does not do the segue,             self.performSegueWithIdentifier(self.showMenuSegue, sender: self). It just stays there.

Comment: From your diagram, you have a login which lets you sign in or add a new user. This first page is the root of a navigation controller. I assume if you sign in with a know account then it pushes to the main app. Your new user dialog is being presented as modal from what I can see. When sign up occurs you have a show/push segue to the app. However you cannot show/push as there is no navigation controller from this point which is probably your issue. Why not dismiss on signup and then force them to log in: or push/show the signup screen rather than present modally.

Comment: That could work, let me try it.

Comment: Yes it works, I just need a way to send the user and pass to the previous screen.

Comment: @Pedro.Alonso The trendy way to do this is with an unwind segue. Rather than dismiss back, you perform an unwind segue to the root controller. The good thing is that this lets you pass back data before it unwinds. In the `viewWillAppear` of the root controller you can use the data passed back. Or add a block property to the signup controller which you call when a new user is signed up. Have the root controller provide the block, which then allows it to pickup the data. e.g. root provides `onSignUp(string username, string password)` block to signup controller which it calls before it dismisses.

Comment: @Pedro.Alonso Posted as an answer now it seem to work.

Comment: I like the onSignUp() idea better, could you explain some more, thanks.

Comment: Not a swift expert, but in ObjC I would: Add a block property to the sign-up controller class which takes the user and password as arguments. In your sign-in controller, in the `prepareForSegue` if using a modal segue or wherever you present the sign-up controller in code, set this property to a block of code which will record the user and password created on sign-up. When you dismiss the sign-up controller simply call the block property with the user and password. The sign-in controller provided the block, so the block can se the sign-in fields to record the user and password provided.

Comment: Well I'm not an Obj-C even noob, so I used the unwind option better. Thanks for your help is working now everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your diagram, you have a login screen which lets you sign in or add a new user. This screen is the root of a navigation controller.

I assume from the diagram that if you sign in with a know account then it pushes to the main app.

Your new user dialog however is being presented as modal from what I can see. When sign up occurs you then have a show/push segue to the app. However you cannot show/push as there is no navigation controller from this point which is probably your issue.

You could either:

1) Dismiss the signup screen and force a login.

2) Push/Show the signup screen rather than presenting it modally.

If you go for 1), then rather than having to dismiss and hard wire you own data pass back, you could use an unwind segue to pass back the username and password to populate the sign-in screen with the new user details.

Answer (score 2):

How do you create the "Login" controller when logging out? Don't you forget to create it with navigation controller to be able to push..

Otherwise please attach some crash information / log

Comment: When logging out I just call  PFuser.logOut() and call the modal segue to the Login controller

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 8, *push segue* is deprecated. You should use *show segue* instead.

Comment: I think the show segues are the ones deprecated, I don't see show in the menu.

Comment: I just check on the Developer portal. *Push* is deprecated and you should use *Show* instead. Which iOS version is your target? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/chapters/StoryboardSegue.html

Comment: Mmm I don't see show in the segues menu, just push, modal, popover, replace and custom

Comment: push is depricated but causes only console warning, not crash